# Rails engine dependencies not loading properly when using Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

I'm developing a Rails 5 engine (https://github.com/Sento/sento-kanban) using a "normal" Rails 5 application mounting the engine from the local disk.

Now I'm looking to add automated testing using Cucumber and I'm facing a dependencies loading issue when running the first scenario, and the first step which is `visit`ing the root page of the app:

```
$ ccucumber
Using the default profile...
Feature: Create a new board
In order to manage my projects
As a project manager
I want to create a new board

  Scenario: Try to create a new board without a title                 # features/boards/create_a_board.feature:6
    Given I'm creating a board with an empty title                    # features/step_definitions/board_steps.rb:1
      File to import not found or unreadable: perfect-scrollbar.
      Load paths:
        /application/spec/test_app/app/assets/config
        /application/spec/test_app/app/assets/images
        /application/spec/test_app/app/assets/javascripts
        /application/spec/test_app/app/assets/stylesheets
        /application/app/assets/config
        /application/app/assets/images
        /application/app/assets/javascripts
        /application/app/assets/stylesheets
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/unobtrusive_flash-3.3.1/lib/assets/javascripts
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/unobtrusive_flash-3.3.1/lib/assets/stylesheets
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/pace-rails-0.1.3/vendor/assets/javascripts
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/pace-rails-0.1.3/vendor/assets/stylesheets
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/modal-responder-rails-1.0.3/vendor/assets/javascripts
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/modal-responder-rails-1.0.3/vendor/assets/stylesheets
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/perfect-scrollbar-rails-0.6.15/vendor/assets/javascripts
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/perfect-scrollbar-rails-0.6.15/vendor/assets/stylesheets
        /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/dragula-rails-9417236588b6/vendor/assets/javascripts
        /usr/local/bundle/bundler/gems/dragula-rails-9417236588b6/vendor/assets/stylesheets
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.1/lib/assets/compiled
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha5/assets/stylesheets
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha5/assets/javascripts
        /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha5/assets/stylesheets (ActionView::Template::Error)
      ./app/assets/stylesheets/sento/kanban/application.scss:22
      ./app/views/layouts/sento/kanban/application.html.slim:11:in `__application_app_views_layouts_sento_kanban_application_html_slim___2646165938008234128_69844567400820'
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:2:in `/^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/'
      ./features/step_definitions/board_steps.rb:2:in `/^I'm creating a board with an empty title$/'
      features/boards/create_a_board.feature:7:in `Given I'm creating a board with an empty title'
```

*Regarding the paths, I'm using Docker, mounting the project as /application/*

It seems the engine dependencies aren't loaded.

Even worst, when I comment the lines requiring perfect-scrollbar and all the other external libraries, keeping only the import of the engine's `style/*`, it also say it cannot find this folder.

Can anyone give me a direction in order to solve this?

Comment: Are you running the cucumber command from a shell inside the docker container?

Comment: Yes I do. The `ccucumber` alias is `docker-compose run web bundle exec cucumber`.